# DRF - ERROR - you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, migration, many-to-many

I am developing a twitter app, the model makes nested tweets through the parent/child approach. I don't want to create a separate class Retweet. Is there a solution to this problem?

```
class TweetLike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tweet = models.ForeignKey("Tweet", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Tweet(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
                                   default=0, 
                                   related_name='tweet_user', 
                                   blank=True, 
                                   through=TweetLike)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
```

Error on ./manage.py migrate

```
ValueError: Cannot alter field tweets.Tweet.likes into tweets.
Tweet.likes - they are not compatible types 
(you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)
```

Comment: you are conflicting User remove through and just keep ManyToManyField(TweetLike)

Comment: ValueError: Cannot alter field tweets.Tweet.likes into tweets.Tweet.likes - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields) - this is when doing so @PavanKumarTS

Comment: also, this error is solved by adding 'through'. The next error is "tweet_like_tweets table not found in the database - even if i set it into the meta class for tweet"

Comment: try `"app_name.Tweet"` instead of `"Tweet"`